# EditorFor string but it's looking for DateTime

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, editorfor

My `EditorFor` for the Title seems to be passing a `DateTime` value rather than a string but I can't see for the life of me as to why, when I comment out the form-group in question it runs perfectly.

Class:

```
public class EventInputModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Event title is required.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage ="The {0} must be between {2} and {1{ characters long.", MinimumLength =1)]
    [Display(Name ="Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DateVal(ErrorMessage = "Incorrect DateTime")]
    [Display(Name ="Date and Time *")]
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Is Public?")]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New Event";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EventInputModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Typo: `must be between {2} and {1{`. Might be related, might not.

Comment: Where is the EditorFor? That's also likely where the bug is.

Comment: @markpsmith Thanks for spotting that, typical it would be something daft

Comment: `EditorFor` is an extension method [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx). Also you have and EditorTemplates for `string` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Solved : 
Typo: must be between {2} and {1{. Might be related, might not. – markpsmith 22 mins ago

Comment: Of course it's silly that the MVC framework code lets this exception slip through. They could catch it and throw a more helpful exception, pointing out the source of the format string.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's just a method like any other. There isn't much the "framework" can do with this. Maybe you'd get more information with debugging symbols or tracing?

Comment: @Luaan somewhere, the `[StringLength]` attribute gets found and its `ErrorMessage` is used as a format string. MVC does this. MVC also passes it to `string.Format()`. There, I would expect a framework to catch exceptions and throw a more helpful exception.